# How can I Hide Selected option from Drop-down list

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide/show the selected option from the Drop-down menu through javascript.

```html
<select id="yselect" class="custom-select" size="3">

                <option value="population">Population</option>
                <option value="trafficHour">Average Traffic Hour</option>
                <option value="grossIncome">Gross Annual Income</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you hide it - it will no longer be selected.

Comment: is there any other way???
I want to move the data from one field to another..... I must hide the first selected one... @fredrik

Comment: So it is an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Asking about a problem other than the one you're really trying to solve. Then you don't want to hide it - you want to remove it and add it do another drop-down? Plain javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide:

CSS

```
#yselect option:selected{
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#yselect option:selected').hide();
```